# Can't perform POST function to SQL db using Formik?

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm having a problem getting my app's form to submit data to my SQL database.

I'm able to successfully insert a record using a POST request on Postman, but for whatever reason my form just doesn't connect to the backend.

I'm fairly new to Java and have been relying on tutorials up until this point, and therefore I was hoping someone could potentially look over my code and try and spot the issue if possible?

It's probably a really dumb error or something that I've missed altogether.

I've uploaded the repository on [Github](https://github.com/adamross94/sernwebapp).

The code for the form can be seen below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import axios from 'axios';


function CreateAEMonthlySitRep() {
const initialValues = {
    attendancest1:"",
    attendancest2:"", 
    attendancesto:"", 
    fourhourspatientst1:"",
    fourhourspatientst2:"", 
    fourhourspatientsto:"", 
    fourtwelvehourspatients:"",
    twelvehourspatients:"", 
    emergencyadmissionst1:"",
    emergencyadmissionsto:"", 
    emergencyadmissionst2:"", 
    admissionstother:"",
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    attendancest1: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."),
    attendancest2: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."), 
    attendancesto: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."), 
    fourhourspatientst1: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."),
    fourhourspatientst2: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."), 
    fourhourspatientsto: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."), 
    fourtwelvehourspatients: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."),
    twelvehourspatients: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."), 
    emergencyadmissionst1: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."),
    emergencyadmissionsto: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."), 
    emergencyadmissionst2: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."), 
    admissionstother: Yup.number().required("You must input a valid number."),
});

const onSubmit = (data) => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/maesitrep", data).then((response) => {
        console.log("Data added successfully.");
    });
};

return (
    <div>
         <link
       rel="stylesheet"
       href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
       integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
       crossOrigin="anonymous"
  />
  <div className="createAEMonthlySitRepPage">
    <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
      <table className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colSpan={10} scope="col"><p className="text-end px-5 pt-2">Attendances by A&amp;E Type</p></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" />
            <th scope="col"><center>Type 1</center></th>
            <th scope="col"><center>Type 2</center></th>
            <th scope="col"><center>Other</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <Formik 
            initialValues={initialValues} 
            onSubmit={onSubmit} 
            validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>Number of A&amp;E Attendances</label></th>
            <td>
              <div className="col p-4">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                  <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="attendancest1"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                  <ErrorMessage name="attendancest1" component="span" />      
                  </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div className="col p-4">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="attendancest2"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                <ErrorMessage name="attendancest2" component="span" />  
                </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div className="col p-4">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="attendancesto"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                <ErrorMessage name="attendancesto" component="span" />  
                </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
      
          </Formik>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema}>          
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>Number of Patients who have had a total time in A&amp;E of  <br />over 4 hours from arrival to discharge,transfer of admission</label></th>
            <td>
              <div className="col p-4">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="fourhourspatientst1"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage name="fourhourspatientst1" component="span" />  
                        </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div className="col p-4">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="fourhourspatientst2"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage name="fourhourspatientst2" component="span" />  
                        </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div className="col p-4">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="fourhourspatientsto"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage name="fourhourspatientsto" component="span" />  
                        </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </Formik>
          <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema}>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>Number of patient who have waited 4-12 hours in A&amp;E from <br />decision to admit to admission</label></th>
            <td colSpan={3}>
              <div className="col-7 p-4 mx-auto">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="fourtwelvehourspatients"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                         <ErrorMessage name="fourtwelvehourspatients" component="span" />  
                         </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </Formik>
          <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema}>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>Number of patient who have over 12 hours in A&amp;E from <br />decision to admit to admission</label></th>
            <td colSpan={3}>
              <div className="col-7 p-4 mx-auto">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="twelvehourspatients"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                         <ErrorMessage name="twelvehourspatients" component="span" />  
                         </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </Formik>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
      <table className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colSpan={10} scope="col"><p className="text-end px-5 pt-2">Number of Admissions</p></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema}>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>Emergency Admissions via A&E - Type 1</label></th>
            <td colSpan={3}>
              <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="emergencyadmissionst1"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage name="emergencyadmissionst1" component="span" />  
                        </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </Formik>
          <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema}>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>Emergency Admissions via A&E - Type 2</label></th>
            <td colSpan={3}>
              <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="emergencyadmissionst2"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                         <ErrorMessage name="emergencyadmissionst2" component="span" />  
                         </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </Formik>
          <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema}>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>Emergency Admissions via A&E - Other A&E Department</label></th>
            <td colSpan={3}>
              <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="emergencyadmissionsto"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                         <ErrorMessage name="emergencyadmissionsto" component="span" />  
                         </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </Formik>
          <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema}>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>Other Emergency Admissions</label></th>
            <td colSpan={3}>
              <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Form>
                <Field 
                        id=""
                        type="number"
                        name="admissionstother"
                        placeholder="0"
                        />
                          <ErrorMessage name="admissionstothe" component="span" />  
                          </Form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </Formik>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema}>
          <Form>
   
        <button type="submit">Save Data</button>
       
        </Form>
        </Formik>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
);
}
export default CreateAEMonthlySitRep;
```

The code for the route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { MAESitRep } = require('../models')


router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
const listOfMAESitRep = await MAESitRep.findAll();
res.json(listOfMAESitRep);
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
const post = req.body;
await MAESitRep.create(post); 
res.json(post);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Server index.js code:

```
const express = require ("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = require('./models');

// Routers
const maesitrepRouter = require("./routes/MAESitRep"); 
app.use("/maesitrep", maesitrepRouter);

db.sequelize
.sync()
.then(() => {
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on Port 3001");
});
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Kind regards,

Adam

Comment: Is this really related to the <sql> _language_? (I see no SQL above, do you expect a SQL answer?)

Comment: Is it intentional that every row is its own separate form but has the same set of initial values and the same submit handler? Specifically, the submit button is all by its lonesome, not related to the other form values. You should have one Formik component that wraps the entire table.